# dataGridView no finaliza la edición de los datos, tras el valor de una celda

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo un gridview que se carga desde una query  y que tiene varios campos, uno de estos es un combobox que se agrega de manera manual que puede tener 3 valores:
- Nulo si el usuario no ha seleccionado nada
- A 
- C

El problema es que al ejecutar un codigo para obtener los datos de la grilla,
Si mi ultimo valor en la celda fue C y el usuario lo cambio, deja por defecto el valor C y no toma como valor A.
Otro ejemplo de esto podría ser que si el usuario deja su preferencia vacia, pero luego desea cambiarla, el valor que obtiene mi string es "nulo"

Existe algún método para decir que he finalizado la edición del datagridview completo?

Solo he intentado :

```
 Midatagridview.EndEdit();
```

------ El código utilizado para recorrer el gridview-----

```
   int row = 0;
   foreach(DataGridViewRow dr in MiDataGridView.Rows){
      if(MiDataGridView.Columns[5].Value!=System.DBNull.Value||MiDataGridView.Columns[5].Value!=System.DBNull.Null){
             string valor_grilla =(string)MiDataGridView.Columns[5].Value; //En este string estoy guardando el valor, pero me guarda la opcion que tenia seleccionada antes, no la  preferencia del usuario (en el caso que sea nueva)
      }

      row = row +1;
   }
```

Pero este no realiza nada.

Comment: como llenas el grid? usas BindingSouce? DataTable?

Comment: utilizo un datatable, pero el usuario puede editar en el grid después de traer los datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa lo siguiente:

```
   if(Midatagridview.IsCurrentCellDirty){
        Midatagridview.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
```

Saludos

Comment: graciasss, funciono de maravilla